# Can I convert my imessage sticker app to an android sticker app?

Tags: android, ios, imessage

I would like to know if I can convert my imessage sticker app into an android sticker app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, there is no implementation of the concept of sticker apps on Android, at least not in the same form as it exists on iOS.

The closest you can get is by building your own input method, and including images with your stickers in it. A detailed walkthrough can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Beware though, as the images sent from these alternative keyboards aren't compatible with every app - but then again, iMessage stickers are also only useful in iMessage itself.

Answer (score 0):

No. When your app is built using a native language it wouldnt be possible as Android has a different runtime and platform.

There are ways to deploy multi platform but most of them are built using phonegap or ionic. Xamarin seems to be able to do multiplatform using native but as i havent tried it im not sure.